# how to correct the misencoded string?

Tags: python, encoding, mp3, mutagen

i used [mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) to read the mp3 metadata, since the id3 tag is read in as unicode but in fact it is GBK encoded. how to correct this in python?

```
audio = EasyID3(name)
title = audio["title"][0] 
print title
print repr(title)
```

produces

```
µ±Äã¹Âµ¥Äã»áÏëÆðË­
u'\xb5\xb1\xc4\xe3\xb9\xc2\xb5\xa5\xc4\xe3\xbb\xe1\xcf\xeb\xc6\xf0\xcb\xad'
```

but in fact it should be in GBK (chinese).

```
当你孤单你会想起谁
```

Comment: GBK isn't part of the standard, so mutagen is quite right to get this wrong. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3

Valid encodings are latin1, utf16 (with BOM or BE), and utf8, and are denoted by a byte field.

But see any of the good answers for how to fix this, I'm just making an observation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the string has been decoded to unicode using the wrong encoding (latin-1).

You need to encode it to a byte string and then decode it back to unicode using the correct encoding.

```
title = u'\xb5\xb1\xc4\xe3\xb9\xc2\xb5\xa5\xc4\xe3\xbb\xe1\xcf\xeb\xc6\xf0\xcb\xad'
print title.encode('latin-1').decode('gbk')
当你孤单你会想起谁
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's auto-decoding using `latin1`. To fix:

```
>>> title = u'\xb5\xb1\xc4\xe3\xb9\xc2\xb5\xa5\xc4\xe3\xbb\xe1\xcf\xeb\xc6\xf0\xcb\xad'
>>> print title.encode('latin1').decode('GBK')
当你孤单你会想起谁
```

Tested in Python 2.x but should work fine in 3 as well.