# using edeD3 to change encoding of mp3 tags

Tags: encoding, mp3, metadata

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190904/how-to-correct-the-misencoded-string) which is my exact starting point: Chinese-encoded metadata on mp3 files. I want to re-encode all my metadata as utf-8 so that Banshee can read it.

I can't figure out how to get eyeD3 to do that. I can decode individual tags as per that previous link, but I can't make eyeD3 change the actual text encoding of the mp3 file itself, so those tags can be rewritten in the proper encoding. I tried reading all the data into variables (below, 't' is the properly encoded title), then calling:

```
tag.clear()
tag.update(eyeD3.ID3_V2_4)
tag.setTitle(t)
```

That tells me: `ValueError: ID3 vNone.None is not supported.` Not what I was expecting.

I tried `tag.setTextEncoding('utf-8')`, but that tells me `eyeD3.tag.TagException: Invalid encoding`. All the other encodings I try give me the same error message.

`eyeD3.TAGS2_2_TO_TAGS_2_3_AND_4` looks promising, but it's a dictionary of cryptic letter codes that mean nothing to me.

Can someone tell me how to change the version of the tags to something that supports utf-8, then change the file encoding to utf-8 and write the metadata back in?

Comment: Ok, I've been able to use the commandline version of the library to set the version, encoding and metadata of the files, but weirdly cannot read existing data. Ie, I can use the python library to read the data but not write it, and the command line library to write the data but not read it…

Comment: Aaaaaaaand… I figured it out. Setting the text encoding should look like `tag.setTextEncoding(eyeD3.UTF_8_ENCODING)`. Sorry~

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somebody's already created something that does this:

http://code.google.com/p/id3-to-unicode/

It's pretty easy to use.  Just download the latest version of the script from the website, make sure you have the eyeD3 and chardet python modules installed (a quick `sudo apt-get install python-eyed3 python-chardet` did the trick for me in ubuntu), and run the script with the -h flag to see how to use it.

My only complaint is that the script assumes that your music is organized like artist/album/01 track name.mp3, and uses path/file information to fill in missing tags.  I disabled this in the latest version (http://id3-to-unicode.googlecode.com/files/id3_to_unicode_1.1.py) by commenting out lines 126-138.

Answer (score 0):

[Eric Abrahamsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741231/eric-abrahamsen) figured out, that setting the text encoding should look like
`tag.setTextEncoding(eyeD3.UTF_8_ENCODING)` instead of
`tag.setTextEncoding('utf-8')`.